# django - rest framework response content negotiation not happening

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I upgraded `djangorestframework` from version **3.2.5** to version **3.5.3**.
Since then `response` content negotiation (not sure if term is correct) is not happening.

Sample code:

```
serializer = SessionSerializer(active_sessions, many=True)
print(serializer.data)
response = Response(serializer.data)
print(response.data)
```

Output when using version **3.2.5**

```
[OrderedDict([('session_id', '16a635d0-0f7a-4366-b648-a907ea4f4692')])]
{"count": 1, "previous": null, "results": [{"session_id": "16a635d0-0f7a-4366-b648-a907ea4f4692"}]}
```

Output when using **3.5.3**

```
[OrderedDict([('session_id', '16a635d0-0f7a-4366-b648-a907ea4f4692')])]
{"msg": "[OrderedDict([('session_id', '16a635d0-0f7a-4366-b648-a907ea4f4692')])]"}
```

I am using below rendered

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
    ),
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: missing `count`, `previous` etc keys  (the pagination support keys) are missing in `3.5.3`. Is that you are trying to indicate?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I don't thin this is an version mismatch issue, rather than you may missed the pagination class

Comment: `'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my.serializers.CustomPagination',` was there earlier and it is there now.